# How to pass Id from child component to the Parent where I called my API

Tags: javascript

As I am new in react js, in advance I am thankful to all of you.

I am using React table, and I have `TablestableRows.js` so my button for delete is here but when I call API in this child component it's not working. when I call my API in the parent component `AllLeads.js` then it's working the API, so now I want to delete one of my elements through an API call. this is the code and API that I am using for this tutorial.

This is the Mapping component that all my data mapping through it:

```
  import {
              Table,
              Tbody,
              Text,
              Th,
              Thead,
              Tr,
              useColorModeValue,
            } from "@chakra-ui/react";
            // Custom components
            import Card from "../Card/Card.js";
            import CardBody from "../Card/CardBody.js";
            import TablesTableRow from "./TablesTableRow";
            import React from "react";
            
            const LeadsTable = ({captions, data }) => {
              const textColor = useColorModeValue("gray.700", "white");
              return (
                <Card overflowX={{ sm: "scroll" }} p={6} borderRadius='lg'  h={"85vh"}>
                  <CardBody>
                    <Table variant='simple' color={textColor} >
                      <Thead>
                        <Tr my='.8rem' pl='0px' color='gray.400'>
                          {captions.map((caption, idx) => {
                            return (
                              <Th color='gray.400' key={idx} ps={idx === 0 ? "0px" : null}>
                                {caption}
                              </Th>
                            );
                          })}
                        </Tr>
                      </Thead>
                      <Tbody>
                        {data.map((row) => {
                          return (
                            <TablesTableRow
                              key={`${row._id}`}
                              id={`${row._id}`}
                              name={row.name}
                              email={row.email}
                              phone_no={row.phone_no}
                              domain={row.domain}
                              lead_state={row.lead_state}
                              lead_date={row.lead_date}
                              graduation_status={row.graduation_status}
            
                              // graduation_status
                            />
                          );
                        })}
                      </Tbody>
                    </Table>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              );
            };
            
            export default LeadsTable;
```

This is the component that I have CTA Button on it:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
           Badge,
           Button,
           Flex,
           Td,
           Text,
           Tr,
           useColorModeValue,
       } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deleteLeadsAdmin, getLeadsById } from "../../redux/Leads/actionCreator";
                    
const TablesTableRow = (props) => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch
     const {id, name, email, phone_no, lead_state, lead_date, graduation_status } = props;
     const textColor = useColorModeValue("gray.700", "white");
     const colorStatus = useColorModeValue("white", "gray.400");
     const createdProjectDate = lead_date.split("T", 1);
                    
     const onDeleteLead = (e)=>{
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log(id,'id')
                        dispatch(deleteLeadsAdmin(id)).then(res=>{
                          console.log(res,'leads deleted by is')
                        })
     }
                    
     return (
                        <Tr>
                          <Td pl="0px">
                            <Flex align="center" py=".8rem" minWidth="100%" flexWrap="nowrap">
                              <Flex direction="column">
                                <Text
                                  fontSize="md"
                                  color={textColor}
                                  fontWeight="bold"
                                  minWidth="100%"
                                >
                                  {name}
                                </Text>
                              </Flex>
                            </Flex>
                          </Td>
                          <Td>
                            <Flex direction="column">
                              <Text fontSize="sm" color={textColor}
                                fontWeight="normal">
                                {email}
                              </Text>
                            </Flex>
                          </Td>
                          <Td>
                            <Flex direction="column">
                              <Text fontSize="sm" color={textColor}
                                fontWeight="normal">
                                {phone_no}
                              </Text>
                            </Flex>
                          </Td>
                          <Td>
                            <Badge
                              // bg={status === "Active" ? "green.400" : bgStatus}
                              bg={lead_state === 0 ? 'pink.500' : lead_state === 1 ? 'green.400' : lead_state === 2 ? 'gray.600' : 'orange.200'}
                              // color={status === "Active" ? "white" : colorStatus}
                              color={lead_state === 0 && 1 && 2 ? 'white' : colorStatus}
                              fontSize="16px"
                              p="3px 10px"
                              borderRadius="8px"
                            >
                    
                              {lead_state === 0 ? 'Raw Lead' : lead_state === 1 ? 'Converted Leads' : lead_state === 2 ? 'Registerd Leads' : '-'}
                            </Badge>
                          </Td>
                    
                          <Td>
                            <Flex direction="column">
                              <Text fontSize="sm" color={textColor}
                                fontWeight="normal">
                                {graduation_status}
                              </Text>
                            </Flex>
                          </Td>
                    
                          {/* graduation_status */}
                          <Td>
                            <Flex direction="column">
                              <Text fontSize="sm" color={textColor}
                                fontWeight="normal">
                                {createdProjectDate} // this is the date of each new leads
                              </Text>
                            </Flex>
                          </Td>
                        
                          <Td>
                            <Button p="0px" bg="transparent" variant="hover" _hover={{ bg: "#1e91ff", color: "#fff" }} me="10px">
                              <Link to={`/leads/all-leads/${id}`} >
                    
                                <Text
                                  fontSize="md"
                                  color={textColor}
                    
                                  fontWeight="bold"
                                  cursor="pointer"
                                  _hover={{ color: "#fff" }}
                                  p={5}
                    
                                >
                                  Edit
                                </Text>
                    
                              </Link>
                    
                            </Button>
                            <Button p="0px" bg="transparent" variant="hover" _hover={{ bg: "#f54b4b", color: "#fff" }} 
                onClick={onDeleteLead}>
                            <Link to={`/leads/all-leads/${id}`} >
                              <Text
                                fontSize="md"
                                color={textColor}
                                fontWeight="bold"
                                cursor="pointer"
                                _hover={{ color: "#fff" }}
                                p={5}
                              >
                                Delete
                              </Text>
                              </Link>
                            </Button>
                          </Td>
                        </Tr>
                      );
                    }
                    
                    export default TablesTableRow;
```

This is the parent where I call my APIs:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
           Flex,
           WrapItem,
           Button,
           Box,
           useColorModeValue,
       } from "@chakra-ui/react";
 import LeadsTable from "../../component/LeadsTable//LeadsTable";
 import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
 import {
            deleteLeadsAdmin,
            getLeadsForAdmin,
        } from "../../redux/Leads/actionCreator";
 import HeadTitle from "../../component/HeadTitle/HeadTitle";
 import { BodyMain } from "../../component/HeadTitle/BodyMain";
 import { useParams } from "react-router";

 function AllLeads() {
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const query = useParams();
                    
     const [listingLeadsList, setListingLeadsList] = useState([]); // use in listing project list
     const [pageLeads, setPageLeads] = useState(5); // use in listing project list
                    
     console.log(pageLeads, "page number");
                    
     const [id, setID] = useState([]);
     console.log(id, "this is the id of leads all leads=");
                    
     const chagneNextPage = () => {
          setPageLeads(pageLeads + 1);
     };
     const chagnePreviousPage = () => {
          setPageLeads(pageLeads - 1);
     };
                    
     // console.log(currentPage,' currentPage')
     // console.log('this is the leads', listingLeadsList)

     const ProjectsForAdmin = () => {
         dispatch(getLeadsForAdmin(pageLeads))
              .then((res) => {
                  if (res.success) {
                      //set data in state to use  in listing
                      setListingLeadsList(res.data.lead);
                      console.log(res.data.lead._id, "LEADS LIST FRON END");
                      // setID(res.data.lead[1]._id);
                      setPageLeads(res.data.next.page);
                      // setCurrentPage(res.data.next.pag);
                  } else {
                      console.log("err Leads", res);
                  }
              })
          .catch((err) => console.log("errr leads", err));
      };
      useEffect(() => {
                        ProjectsForAdmin();
                      }, []);
                    
                      // const onDeleteLead = (e)=>{
                      //   e.preventDefault();
                      //   console.log(id,'id')
                      //   dispatch(deleteLeadsAdmin(id)).then(res=>{
                      //     console.log(res,'leads deleted by is')
                      //   })
                      // }
                    
                      const pagesQuantity = 12;
                    
                      return (
                        <Flex
                          flexDirection="column"
                          h={"100vh"}
                          px="30px"
                          bg={useColorModeValue("#f3f2f1", "gray.900")}
                        >
                          <HeadTitle title="Leads List" />
                          <BodyMain>
                            <WrapItem w={"100%"}>
                              <Box
                                bg={useColorModeValue("#fff", "gray.800")}
                                borderRadius="lg"
                                w={"100%"}
                              >
                                <LeadsTable
                                  padding={20}
                                  title={"Leads Table"}
                                  captions={[
                                    "Name",
                                    "Email",
                                    "Phone",
                                    "Status",
                                    "Graduation Status",
                                    "Date",
                                    "Action",
                                  ]}
                                  data={listingLeadsList}
                                />
                    
                                {/* <Button type='submit' onClick={onDeleteLead} me={10}>delete</Button> */}
                                <Button type="submit" onClick={chagnePreviousPage}>
                                  Previous
                                </Button>
                              </Box>
                            </WrapItem>
                          </BodyMain>
                        </Flex>
                      );
                    }
                    
                    export default AllLeads;
```

**Issue resolved**: it was about hooks and now I am able to send the id to the API URL useDispatch()

Answer (score 0):

you can try moving you delete function up a level to the parent and passing it to your child table as a prop, then the function will be called at a level above.

Comment: I tried but it's not just one component, if we think about the level of component the button is in the third level component and the second component is the mapping component that going to map over the API data that is why,
I reveled the edit button by passing Id from edit button to URL and taking that Id in parent component after that i passed that Id to the API where my API is in parent component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).